What is UWP app debugger using under the hood for the "Select Element" function?
If you attach with a Visual Studio to your own UWP/C++/CX app (or someone else's) the UI debugger shows these debugging controls on top of the UWP window. My interest is the workings of the "Select Element" button (this one):

It acts as an old "Spy++" tool for the Win32 GUI apps by selecting a XAML control under the mouse pointer.
So first question: what do they use under the hood to do that?
I'm also curious, how do they later construct the "Live Visual Tree" for such control?

My goal in learning all this is to write a version of the Spy++ tool to deconstruct UWP apps to get the following from a control that I point to with a mouse:

For controls with a tied event, I need to get the address of the event handler.

To get XAML details of a control (or properties.)



Before the "Live Visual Tree" there was WPF Snoop. Snoop apparently used dll injection. UWP "supports" dll injection. The source to Snoop is availiable on GitHub.
